# Need help refactoring my redundant code (using MySQL/PHP to populate/build 3 select lists)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, refactoring

I have a meal/recipe database, used for creating daily meal plans.  I need to create 3 different select lists (breakfast, lunch, dinner) to display the available recipe options, for each **meal_name**.

As of now I'm using separate queries for each of the above, and separate builds to display the results for each list.

**The query for Lunch:**

```
  // Lunch options
  $sql = "SELECT plan_date,
    plan_meal,
    plan_recipe,
    recipe_name,
    recipe_serving_size
    FROM recipe_plans
    LEFT JOIN $table_meals ON meal_id = plan_meal    
    LEFT JOIN $table_recipes ON recipe_id = plan_recipe
    WHERE plan_date = '".$date."'
    AND meal_name = 'Lunch'
    AND plan_owner = '".$user_name."'
    ORDER BY recipe_name";
    $rc = $DB_LINK->Execute($sql);
    DBUtils::checkResult($rc, NULL, NULL, $sql);

  // Scan the rows of the SQL result
  while (!$rc->EOF) {
    $recipeList[($rc->fields['plan_recipe'])] = $rc->fields['recipe_name'] . " (" . $rc->fields['recipe_serving_size'] . ")";
    $rc->MoveNext();
  }
```

**and the build:**

```
// Scan the fields in the SQL result row
// Print all existing Meals, and some new ones
$minShow = 1;
$maxShow = 1;  // only build 1 while testing
for ($i = 0; $i < (isset($MealPlanObj->mealplanItems[$date]) && ($i < $maxShow) ? count($MealPlanObj->mealplanItems[$date]) : 0) + $minShow; $i++) {
  if ($i < (isset($MealPlanObj->mealplanItems[$date]) ? count($MealPlanObj->mealplanItems[$date]) : 0)) {
    // If it is an existing meal item, then set it
    $meal = $MealPlanObj->mealplanItems[$date][$i]['meal']; // meal_id
    $servings = $MealPlanObj->mealplanItems[$date][$i]['servings'];
    $recipe = $MealPlanObj->mealplanItems[$date][$i]['id']; // recipe_id
  } else {
    // It is a new one, give it blank values
    $meal = NULL;
    $servings = $defaultServings;
    $recipe = NULL;
  }
  // The HTML Code to build the select list for 'Lunch'
}
```

The above code has been duplicated for each meal_name, because that's where my limited skills have left me, lol.

***The question is**: rather than writing a separate select and build statement for each of the 3 conditions (breakfast, lunch, dinner), how can I write just 1, to output them all?*

Comment: I don't understand. There is no reference to `meal_name` in the php code. What is the issue? Also I think you can probably make some of those loops `foreach` to make it a bit easier to read your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already used variables to build the SQL query, so you can introduce just another variable like `$meal_name`. This variable you can apply to your SQL statement. Instead of:

```
$sql = "SELECT mplan_date,
  ...
  AND meal_name = 'Lunch'
  ...
```

you will write then:

```
$meal_name = 'Lunch';
...
$sql = "SELECT mplan_date,
  ...
  AND meal_name = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($meal_name) . "'
  ...
```

Note the use of the function `mysqli_real_escape_string()`, although not absolutely necessary in this example, it's very important to escape all variables you add to an SQL statement, if you are not absolutely sure what's inside the variable. Your example code is vulnerable to SQL-injection.

After that you can go a step further and pack the code into a function:

```
function buildSqlQuery($meal_name, $date, $user_name)
{
  $sql = "SELECT mplan_date,
    ...
    ORDER BY recipe_name";
  return $sql;
}

$sqlForBreakfast = buildSqlQuery('Breakfast', '2000-01-01', 'teddy');
$sqlForLunch = buildSqlQuery('Lunch', '2000-01-01', 'teddy');
$sqlForDinner = buildSqlQuery('Dinner', '2000-01-01', 'teddy');
```

Comment: so this helps me with the 1st half of my problem...but how can i automate the actual build for each of the 3 lists?

Comment: In the same manner, we put the code for building the sql select-statement into a function, we can put the code for executing the query, and for writing to HTML into functions. Just pass the variables `$sqlForbreakfast` to the query-function and then the `$recipeList` to the writing-function. This we can repeat for all three cases.

Comment: ^^^ that should've been obvious.  guess i got "paralysis of analysis" by over-thinking it, lol.  thx again!